# Fluid row issue with a checkbox input in Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am having trouble formatting a row of dynamic inputs. Anytime I have checkboxInput as part of my fluidRow, it jumps to a new line instead of placing the action buttons directly to the right of the checkbox. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the current code:

```html
  #Dynamic UI based on how many cohorts exist;
  cohort_ui = eventReactive(c(input$save_cohort, input$reset_cohorts, input$delete_cohort1, input$delete_cohort2), {
    bootstrapPage(
      strong("Combine Cohorts"),
      lapply(1:length(names(cohorts)), function(i) {
        fluidRow(column(width = 12, checkboxInput(paste0("active_cohort",i), label = names(cohorts)[i], value = FALSE), 
                        actionButton(paste0("delete_cohort",i), "Delete"), actionButton(paste0("rename_cohort",i), "Rename"), 
                        textInputRow(paste0("rename_cohort_text",i), label= NULL, placeholder = "Enter new cohort name")))
      }),
      radioButtons("join_cohorts", label = "Join Operation", choices = c("Union", "Intersection", "Difference"), selected = NULL),
      textInput("join_cohorts_name", label = "New Cohort Name", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),
      actionButton("join_cohorts_save", "Save")
    )
  })
  output$cohort_ui = renderUI({cohort_ui()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the checkbox is a block-level element. You need to add css to make it inline. Short example:

```
library(shiny)

mycss <- "
.mycheckbox .shiny-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(mycss),
  span(class="mycheckbox", checkboxInput("checkbox", "checkbox")),
  actionButton("button", "button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! Never heard of block-level element but it makes sense.